# Finger print authentication is not working after too many attemps

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-fingerprint-api

On button i'm showing dialog that requesting finger print after too many attempts and dialog still showing after 30 seconds finger pint wont listen, but if i dismiss dialog and go back and come on the fragment that has code for finger print authentication it works

How can I ensure that if dialog is still showing after too many attempts and 30 seconds pass it should listen again after 30 second, is there any call back?

Thanks